# How do I implement average age with deviation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, average

How do I implement average age with deviation in javascript?
I need to make an a Javascript algorithm that:

- Request the name and age of 10 people;
- Print the screen "Average age" of people;
- Print each person's name and deviation from age to average.

I tried to write each prompt one by one but was wondering if there is a way to shorten this code

```
var input = prompt('Enter your name');
var name1 = input;
input = prompt('Enter your age:');
var age1 = parseInt (input);

var input = prompt('Enter your name');
var name2 = input;
input = prompt('Enter your age:');
var age2 = parseInt (input);

[...]

var input = prompt('Enter your name');
var name10 = input;
input = prompt('Enter your age:');
var age10 = parseInt (input);

var average = (age1+age2+age3+age4+age5+age6+age7+age8+age9+age10/10);

console.log(`Average age: ${average}`);
console.log(`Name: ${name1}, Age: ${age1}, Deviance: ${deviance1}`);
console.log(`Name: ${name2}, Age: ${age2}, Deviance: ${deviance2}`);
[...]
console.log(`Name: ${name10}, Age: ${age10}, Deviance: ${deviance10}`);
```

I Don't know how to do the deviance (difference from the analyzed value to the average value)

Comment: For example: the 'deviance1' will be the difference between 'age1' and 'average'

Comment: if (age1 > average) then (age 1 - average = deviation) else if (age1 < average) then (age1 + average = deviation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution below. I have added some comments to the code to assist.
Let me know if you have any questions :)

```js
const MAX_NAMES = 3;

// Each person will be stored in this array below
let people = [];
// Store the total combined age in totalAge variable
let totalAge = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < MAX_NAMES; i++) {
    let nameValue = prompt('Enter your name');
    let ageValue = parseInt(prompt('Enter your age'));
    // Add to the total age
    totalAge += ageValue;
    // we add an object to the array. 'name' and 'age' are the object Keys. We reference the keys to get the values back from the object later
    people.push({ name: nameValue, age: ageValue })
}

// Print the Average Age of People
let averageAge = Math.round(totalAge / people.length);
console.log(`The average age is ${averageAge}`);

//Print each person's name and deviation from age to average.
for(let person in people) {
    console.log(`Name: ${people[person].name} Deviation: ${Math.abs(people[person].age - averageAge)}`);
}
```

Comment: I just removed the Math.round and the Math.abs to be more accurate in the values

Comment: Awesome. Happy to help. Let me know if you have any more questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Each person (with a name and an age) is a singular entity with related properties, so consider using an object instead. Since you have many different people, you can use an array instead, then get the average by iterating over it with `reduce`, and log all differences by iterating with `forEach`:

```js
// this snippet uses 3 people only

const people = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const name = prompt('Enter your name');
  const age = Number(prompt('Enter your age'));
  people.push({ name, age });
}

const average =
      // add up all ages in the array:
  people.reduce((a, { age }) => a + age, 0)
      // divide by the number of people:
  / people.length;
  
people.forEach(({ name, age }) => {
  const deviance = Math.abs(age - average);
  console.log(`Name: ${name}, Age: ${age}, Deviance: ${deviance}`);
});
```